# A verb for "flattery"

Tags: word-choice

The sentences is:

> All the children here stopped. They fawned over the young man, flattery **spilling** out everywhere.

Is there any good replacement for "spilling"? The idea is that suddenly the young man came in and the air was overflowed with flattery. Or is there any other good way to put it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say:

> They (then) fawned over the young man, heaping flattery (of every type) upon him, (so as to catch his attention for but a moment.)

It's a bit poetic, but I think it captures the word picture you are attempting to create.  Anything in the parenthesis can be omitted, but I believe they add a bit more polish.

You could say also say:

> flattery filling the air.

But I think I like the first a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

I think the verb ***gushing*** would work well, because we often use that word in conjunction with heaping praise.

[Interesting ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spilling+praise%2Cgushing+praise%2Csaying+praise%2Cspeaking+praise&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

One definition of *gushing* is:

> **[gushing](http://wordnik.com/words/gushing)** Exuberantly and demonstratively emotional; given to or characterized by gush: as, *a gushing girl; a gushing letter*.

Also:

> **[gush](http://wordnik.com/words/gush)** (*v.*) To make an excessive display of enthusiasm or sentiment.